# Running Docker Compose on Azure Batch Shipyard

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to run compose on Batch Shipyard, or short of directly using compose, allowing multiple containers to work in concert on the same node in a job.  Is this possible?

To clarify - I have several containers that work together parse and process a file.  The main container utilizes other services via network calls.  A simplified example of the compose file that I want to replicate is like so:

```
version: "3"
services:
  primary:
    image: "primaryimage"
    depends_on:
      - secondary
    environment:
      SECONDARY_URL: secondary:8888
  secondary:
    image: secondaryimage
```

Within code run in `primary` there are calls to the URL given in `SECONDARY_URL` to perform some transformations on the data, and a response is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Batch (Shipyard) does not have out-of-the-box support for Docker Compose.

But if you are already familiar with Docker Compose then it's not too hard convert it to shipyard configuration files.

If you want to run MPI/multi-instance tasks (a cluster of nodes cooperating on solving parts of a computation) then take a look at [this](http://batch-shipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/80-batch-shipyard-multi-instance-tasks/).

However, Service Fabric does support Docker Compose. So if Docker Compose support is a strict requirement you could combine you Azure Batch setup with calls to a Service Fabric cluster.

Comment: To translate compose to a shipyard config, would I consider "tasks" in a job configuration to be equivalent to services in compose?  How do containers communicate with each other on the same host?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a fair assumption. 
When you say 'communicate with each other', do you then mean how they coordinate when a task has finished? for that purpose the "coordination command" can still be used (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-mpi#coordination-command). Otherwise the container can communicate using 'regular' means like shared storage (Azure File Storage, RemoteFS) or networking (Azure VNet). You configure this in the Pool configuration.

Comment: I edited my question with a little more context.  Essentially the communication I'm referring to is communication between a couple of containers working together to achieve a single job/task

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There is no way to make tasks dependant on each other and do name resolving like you can in docker compose. A workaround could be to have 'secondary' write its name and ip to shared storage. 'primary' could then pick it up and initiate communication.  In the pool.yaml config you must set `inter_node_communication_enabled: true`. Also Azure Batch Shipyard populates ip addresses of the other compute nodes to the `AZ_BATCH_HOST_LIST` env variable.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explaining the options!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to allow this to work. Note that as a workaround, it is not officially supported and may break at any time.

- Create a Docker image that has Docker itself (more specifically only the client portion is needed) installed with Docker compose.
- For the `tasks` specification in `jobs.yaml`:

  - `docker_image` is the image you created above
  - Either use `resource_files` or `input_data` to ingress your compose file for the task
  - `additional_docker_run_options` should have an item:

    - `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`
  - `command` would be your `docker-compose up` command with whatever arguments you require
- Ensure that your `config.yaml` specifies all of the Docker images required by your Docker compose file and the Docker image that contains Docker/docker-compose itself.